# Using django registration with custom user no explicit username field

Tags: python, django-1.5

In `Django >= 1.5`, Given a [`CustomUser`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) model with `email` as `USERNAME_FIELD` and no other `REQUIRED_FIELDS`:

```
# customapp.models.py
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255, unique=True, db_index=True,
    )
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    ...
```

What is the easiest way to use [`django-registration`](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration), which claims to be compatible with `Custom User Models`, without having to practically rewrite everything?

I've gotten as far as creating my own backend including:

- a custom registration form (sans `username`)
- updated urls to pass the new custom registration form
- subclassing the base views (removing references to `username`)

Now, within the core `models.py` of the `django-registration` app, I find `RegistrationProfile` has [hard](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/src/8f242e35ef7c004e035e54b4bb093c32bf77c29f/registration/models.py?at=default#cl-73) [coded](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/src/8f242e35ef7c004e035e54b4bb093c32bf77c29f/registration/models.py?at=default#cl-107) references to `username` in methods `create_inactive_user` and `create_profile`.

Is there a way to use `django-registration` with this `Custom User Model` without having to modify anything in the core `registration` app?

Answer (score 1):

Since django-registration needs access `user.username`, you can add it to your User:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255, unique=True, db_index=True,
    )
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    ...
    @property
    def username(self):
        return getattr(self, self.USERNAME_FIELD)

    @username.setter
    def set_username(self, value):
        setattr(self, self.USERNAME_FIELD, value)
```

Comment: This looks promising. How would you handle the `create_user(self, email, password=None)` method of my `CustomManager` considering `RegistrationProfile` [wants to pass it a `username`](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/src/8f242e35ef7c004e035e54b4bb093c32bf77c29f/registration/models.py?at=default#cl-84)? Thanks.

Comment: define your create_user accept params like `create_user(self, username, email, password)`?

Comment: I tried that but it seems to cause problems elsewhere like when creating `django-admin.py createsuperuser` or anywhere else a user is created outside of `registration`.